# DNS name from IP address

Tags: powershell

I need to create a list of IP addresses and DNS names. I 
   am trying to get DNS names from IP addresses. I have tried two ways:

1. `try`/`catch` but it ends afterwards.
2. Without and it just outputs DNS names that I can't relate to the IP addresses.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#try {
 Get-Content C:\Users\pintose\Documents\IP_Address.txt | ForEach-Object 
{([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname >> C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt}
# }
 # catch {
 if ($_.Exception.Message -like "*The requested name is valid*") {
            Write-Output "UNREACHABLE" | Out-File C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt }
# }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
$outFile = "C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt"

Get-Content C:\Users\pintose\Documents\IP_Address.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $hash = @{ IPAddress = $_
        hostname = "n/a"     
    }
    $hash.hostname = ([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname
    $object = New-Object psobject -Property $hash
    Export-CSV -InputObject $object -Path $outFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

We create a objects, that have the IPaddress in it and a hostname `n/a` if it cannot be resolved. Then, the object gets exported into the file. You'll get something like:

`192.0.0.1; Server1`

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much! This helped out so much

Answer (score 0):

This uses a workflow so it can do parallel foreach

```
Workflow Get-DNSNames([string[]]$IPAddresses){
    foreach -parallel ($IP in $IPAddresses){
        try{
            @{$IP = $(([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($IP)).hostname)}
        }catch{
            @{$IP = "N/A"}
        }
    }
}

$List = Get-DNSNames -IPAddresses $(Get-Content "C:\IPAddresses.txt").Split("[\r\n]")
$List | Out-File "C:\IPAddresses_Complete.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tried it yet but it looks great. Thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the other solutions offered here, but here are some things you might want to think about.

First, I'd recommend **not** putting the `try{}catch{}` around the whole of the first command. If you are looping through data and just one of them causes an exception, you risk not completing the task. Put the `try{}catch{}` around just the "risky" line of code:

```
Get-Content C:\Users\pintose\Documents\IP_Address.txt | Foreach-Object {
  try {
    ([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname >> C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt
  }
  catch {
    if ($_.Exception.Message -like "*The requested name is valid*") {
      Write-Output "UNREACHABLE" | Out-File C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt
    }
  }
}
```

When you catch the exception, you only write to the text file in the case that "the requested name is valid" (do you mean **in**valid?). You never write anything to the file otherwise. Thus, going back to your original code:

- IF there is an exception caused by **ANY** of the IP addresses
- AND the exception is **NOT** "the requested name is valid" (which I think might be a typo?)
- THEN no error gets written to the file and the script ends without necessarily completing all the IP addresses.

Other things:

You use two methods to write to the file: `>>` and `Out-File`. Probably better to use the PowerShell cmdlet but with the `-Append` switch to ensure you append to the end of the file:

```
([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname | Out-File C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt -Append

Write-Output "UNREACHABLE" | Out-File C:\Users\user\Documents\hostname.txt -Append
```

@restless1987 has suggested a way to ensure you write both the IP address and the hostname (if determined) to the output file. I'd have a look at that to work out what is going on.

My final tip would be to be wary of reading in from `.txt` files with `Get-Content`. They often have trailing (blank) lines and you might want to try to ignore such blanks. Probably not a big issue in this case as it will just mean a failed DNS attempt, but I have seen such things wreak havoc on every mailbox in a (very) large company when used with other commands.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to post and to write the code. It has helped a lot.

Comment: @Charlie Joynt - So, what is your recommendation for reading .txt files? If there are blank lines, they will still need to be handled.

Comment: In a case like this, I'd look to use CSV (with `Import-Csv`) rather than plain text files. If you need to use `Get-Content` on a text file, you could add a check as you loop through each line, e.g. `$_ -match "\S+"` would be a simple check to ensure there is at least one non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
$ip_list = Get-Content ./IP_Address.txt

foreach ($ip in $ip_list) {
    try {
        ([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip)).hostname |
            Out-File -FilePath ./hostname.txt -Append
    }
    catch {
        if ($_.Exception.Message -like "*The requested name is valid*") {
            Write-Output "UNREACHABLE" | Out-File -FilePath './hostname.txt' -Append }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools that can accomplish this, but if you need a quick and dirty solution that you can run just about anywhere this will get the job done.

Using the eternally useful [ps tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx) such as `psloggedon /accepteula \\computername or ip address` you can get who is currently logged in to check if this is the correct machine. For example:

```
c:\pstools>psloggedon /accepteula \\10.0.0.10

loggedon v1.33 - See who's logged on
Copyright ⌐ 2000-2006 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Users logged on locally:
    Error: could not retrieve logon time
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
 Error: could not retrieve logon time
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
 1/12/2015 8:06:51 AM    DOMAIN\user
 Error: could not retrieve logon time
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Users logged on via resource shares:
 1/17/2015 2:26:43 PM    DOMAIN\user
```

Now that you have confirmed that this IP address is the correct one for this user. We just need to lookup the IP address using nslookup.

```
C:\>nslookup 10.0.0.10
Server:  server.domain.com
Address:  10.10.0.1

Name:    Workstation07.server.domain.com
Address:  10.0.0.10
```

Now we know that the computer name for that computer is Workstation07.